# Bootstrap 4 modal not showing on IE

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

i've just made some modals for a webpage and they worked fine on chrome, but i tested them on IE 11 and they didn't show. Here's my code...

```
<section id="my-modals">
        <div class="modal fade" id="tilingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tilingModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="tilingModalTitle">Tiling</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="lead">Parkwood Roofing carry out all tiling work to the tiling manufacturer's specifications.
                            <br><br>
                            Tiling can be a choice of concrete, slate, machine made clay or hand made clay tiles.
                            <br><br>
                            Parkwood Roofing will help you choose the correct tile for the roof pitch and colour to match the building and surroundings.</p>
                        <img src="Images/IMG_5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Contact Us!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="leadworkModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="leadworkModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="leadworkModalTitle">Leadwork</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati vero harum omnis dolorum tempore odio asperiores,
                            <br><br>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio numquam, obcaecati harum dolor atque iste repellat tempore, impedit laudantium. Ad sequi doloremque qui ratione animi omnis magnam nam ipsum aperiam.
                            <br><br>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid inventore iure optio earum voluptate temporibus consectetur sunt eum deserunt corrupti, eos hic at, ullam fuga doloremque assumenda officiis animi! Numquam.</p>
                        <img src="Images/IMG_5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Contact Us!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> <!-- Modals End -->
```

Is there a way to get it working on IE? I've seen that if you remove 'fade' class from the div it fixes this issue but it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: @ZimSystem IE 11